# System monitor network speed monitor not working for LAN but works for my Wi-fi

Tags: system-monitor, network-monitoring

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10. I generally use wi-fi to connect to the internet. But Yesterday my wi-fi router occurred some problem and now it's out for warranty. So temporarily I'm using LAN. System monitor displayed the network speed correctly when I was in wi-fi. But now it's not showing any kinda network speed in System Monitor. I checked the preferences opption but couldn't find a way. I also checked "ksysguard"(KDE's system monitor) and conky. None of them working. How can i solve this? I'm attaching a screenshot to clear the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could well be a bug. Other people seems to have this issue as well, as reported in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1310583.

A user reported it as fixed in kernel version 3.14rc1.

Comment: Yup, now I can see tthe network speed. Thanks for the reply BTW.

Comment: You are welcome! Better late than never ;)